# Recursive enumerator

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, binary-search-tree, yield-return

I'm preparing for an interview, so as an exercise I've implemented algorithm to check if a binary tree is BST.

```
    public static bool CheckBST(this Node root)
    {
        if (root == null) throw new ArgumentException("root");
        Node previous = null;
        foreach (var node in GetNodes(root))
        {
            if (previous != null && node.value <= previous.value)
            {
                return false;
            }
            previous = node;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes(Node root)
    {
        if (root.left != null)
        {
            foreach (var node in GetNodes(root.left))
            {
                yield return node;
            }
        }
        yield return root;
        if (root.right != null)
        {
            foreach (var node in GetNodes(root.right))
            {
                yield return node;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can get rid of foreach loops(still using recursion and yield)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this.
There is no such thing as `yield return many GetNodes(...);` and mixing `yield return` and normal `return` is also not allowed.

However, you can achieve the desired result (deferred execution) using LINQ:

```
private static IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes(Node root)
{
    var result = Enumerable.Empty<Node>();

    if (root.left != null)
        result = result.Concat(GetNodes(root.left));

    result = result.Concat(new [] { root });

    if (root.right != null)
        result = result.Concat(GetNodes(root.right));

    return result;
}
```

Whether this is better than what you currently have is debatable.

Comment: Are you saying that the original code wasn't using deferred execution? I don't think that's true, `yield return` is always deferred, even when combined with `foreach` like this.

Comment: @svick: I don't know how you read that into my answer. The original code used deferred execution and the alternative I provided uses deferred execution. I didn't say anything else.

Comment: “However, you can achieve the desired result (deferred execution) using LINQ” From that, I understood that the original code didn't achieve the desired result. My bad.

Comment: @svick: What I meant with that was: "The original code uses yield, so the desired result is deferred execution. You can't get that result and get rid of foreach when you keep using yield. But you can get deferred execution and get rid of foreach if you abandon yield".